# Helm tpl function pass in file specific variable and global Values

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

Using the helm [function tpl](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#using-the-tpl-function) or other similar functions, how do you pass in a [file specific variable](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/variables/) and the [top level Values](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/values_files/)? Here is a concrete example:

```
# values
template: "{{ .Values.name }} drinks {{ $drink }}"
name: "Tom"

# template
{{- $drink := "coffee" -}}
# how do I pass $drink into tpl???
{{ tpl .Values.template . }}

# expected output
Tom drinks coffee
```

It seems like when I do this it just passes in the `.Values`, but not the file specific `$drink` variable that's defined within the template and I get the error: `error calling tpl`. I don't see anything in the docs for how to merge these values together or just pass them both into the function.

Answer (score 3):

Helm is using a slightly modified version of sprig functions. Most things from sprig are available.

You can use one of the [dict functions](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/dicts.html) to set the value or create a new dict that you pass as context.

```
{{ $_ := set .Values "drink" $drink }}
{{ tpl .Values.template . }}
```

In this case I have set a new key on the `Values` dict.

```yaml
template: "{{ .Values.name }} drinks {{ .Values.drink }}"
```